# Lock directory when uploading to it

Tags: python, django

I've been thinking of updating the directory name with username and datetime when an user uploads files to it. So that the newest upload from a user would show on it. I have a upload function and rename like so:

```
# Check if form is valid and upload   
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(request.FILES, request)
    # Edit the previous folder to have new datetime and user marking if the folder has such.
    currentPath = post_data.get('path').encode("utf-8")
    prevfolder = os.path.basename(post_data.get('path').encode("utf-8"))
    try:
        casename, rest = prevfolder.split(" [",1)
    #print(casename)
        dest = renameOnUpload(request,currentPath, casename)
    except:
        dest = form.path

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/fm/list/%s' % dest)

def renameOnUpload(request,path,casename):
    datetime_string = get_currenttime()
    user_string = " ["+ request.user.username + "]"
    newcasename = casename+user_string.encode("utf-8")+datetime_string
    dest = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), newcasename)
    if not path == dest:
        fmoper.move(path, dest)
    else:
        dest = path
    return dest
```

fmoper.move

```
def move(src, dst, replace=False):
    ensure_dir(dst)             # Ensure that we have a destination folder, if not create it. 
    if not replace and os.path.exists(dst):
        dst = existname(dst)
    return shutil.move(src, dst)
```

So it uploads the files and does a move after. Which causes problems when an user is uploading and another one uploads at the same time, renaming the folder in the process causing one uploader to upload to an folder that doesn't exist.

Is there some neat way I could lock the folder when an user is uploading to it? currentPath is the folder uploaded to and dest the renamed one.

Comment: I can't see a justification for locking, can you explain further what happens if your app doesn't have any folder locking (not even your actual locking)? thanks. I am thinking about temporal files, temporal directories, timestamp based file renaming, pre_save signals and other techniques to avoid filenames collission, but folder locking just doesn't fit.